# htaccess reverse directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

It is possible to let htaccess look for a specific file related to the url and go back one step if not found?

Example:

```
/example/here/where/from
```

Htaccess looks if the '/example/here/where/from' is indeed a file of some sort(/example/here/where/from.php) if this fails it goes back one step and checks if ' '/example/here/where' is a file(/example/here/where.php) and so forth.

If it had to go back in the tree assume them as parameters as in:

/example/here.php

$_GET['params'] = 'where/from';

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

spelling

Comment: Is this of a fixed depth (e.g. in you example it is maximum 4 items deep), or do you want to be able to handle infinite depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very tricky but here is a code that recursively traverse to parent dir of the given REQUEST_URI and it supports infinite depth.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of current REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/ [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then 
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

#### Explanation:

Let's say original URI is: `/index/foo/bar/baz`. Also let's say that `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php` exists but no other php files exist under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

RewriteRule #1 has a regex that is breaking current REQUEST_URI into 2 parts:

1. All but lowest subdir into `$1` which will be `index/foo/bar` here
2. Lowest subdir into `$2` which will be `baz` here

RewriteCond checks whether `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php` (which translates to whether `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index/foo/bar/baz.php`) is **NOT** a valid file.

If condition succeeds then it is internally redirected to `$1/` which is `index/foo/bar/` here.

RewriteRule #1's logic is repeated again to make REQUEST_URI as (after each recursion):

1. `index/foo/bar/`
2. `index/foo/`
3. `index/`

At this point RewriteCond fails for rule # 1 because `${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php` exists there.

My RewriteRule #2 says forward to `$1.php` if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` is a valid file. Note that RewriteRule #2 has regex that matches everything but last slash and puts it into `$1`. This means checking whether `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php` is a valid file (and it indeed is).

At this point mod_rewrite processing is complete as no further rule can be fired since both RewriteCond fails after that, therefore `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php` gets duly served by your Apache web server.

Comment: I was so exhausted figuring out recursive logic, I skipped explanation part, adding it now :)

Comment: @john: Added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this answer this question, could you take a look at this? [question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496267/htaccess-permission-denied-directory-index-shown

Comment: Great answer, i've been looking for something like this, for a long time.
Although i had to do some adjustment to work for me:
1. Remove the "RewriteBase /"
2. Switch:
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    for
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

The second fix is to work with pages without the .php, to add it automatically.

For example:
www.somesime.com/home.php/a/b/c
www.somesime.com/home/a/b/c

Both will work.