# Htaccess permission denied / Directory index shown

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, routes

I asked a [question]: [htaccess reverse directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487909/htaccess-reverse-directory) here about reverse routing. However I keep getting the directory view instead of the file in question.

For example: I go to /img/header.jpg I get the content of the folder /img/ while the file header.jpg exists. I added -Indexes in the options but that just results into a 403 forbidden access message.

How should I edit my htaccess to show imgs/js/css etc but still keep the recursive structure?

**current htacces:**

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
 # Turn mod_rewrite on
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/ [L]

 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

thanks in advance

**Edit**

I have tried adding the following line directly after RewriteBase /:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This work for most files. Only this should only work when it are images/css/js/ico/etc. I think at the moment if it finds a php file directly it would work to.

What I cant seem to figure out is how to get the remaining parameters.

```
 /index/foo/bar/for/
```

File that should be found is foo , how do I get the 2 remaining parameters in a $_GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of crrent REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/ [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then 
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comments this solution fills a query parameter `param` with the remainder of a path:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of crrent REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:param=)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?param=$2/%1 [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then 
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Cool, this seems to work. How do I get the left over params as $_GET['params']? I assume the params are lost when the third statement checks?

Comment: I am not sure about `$_GET['params']` as that is basically a query parameter. As you can see these rules are not manipulating any query string. It would be better if you can tell me what is your original URI and what behavior you expect out of it?

Comment: I'm expecting: /some/place/foo/bar to go to /some/place.php get the variable $_GET['param] = 'foo/bar';

Comment: Check the **EDIT** section for the code you want. Just one request: please don't add any more complications, its already pretty complex :)

Comment: Thanks alot :) for now I wont add anything :P