# Htaccess reverse lookup directory tree script exist

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to let htaccess run up directories until it finds one and keep normal get's intact ? for example:

```
/foo/bar/foobar/test/something?foo=bar&bar=foo
```

Where is the script is /foo/bar/foobar.php and foobar.php has:

```
array(2)
[foo] = bar,
[bar] = foo
```

And test/something are passed somewhere for example in an other  get name 'path/params'.

I got this but it doesn't handle gets nicely:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:param=)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?param=$2/%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Currently I am running into the following problem:

I have a page that's called /page.php but this page.php has checks for certain 'options' like for example /page/homepage. This works but when I add /page/homepage?foo=bar the current htaccess makes it 'homepage/foo=bar' instead of a separate get.
I explode the params get on / and gives me the following:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'page' (length=4)
  1 => string 'homepage' (length=8)
  2 => string 'foo=bar' (length=7)
```

The foo=bar shouldn't be there and should be $_GET['foo'] or whatever the name is and if more, more named gets after it. for example:

```
array (size=3)
  params => string 'page/homepage' (length=13)
  foo => string 'bar' (length=3)
  bar => string 'foo' (length=3)
```

The current htaccess see the first get as part of the 'param'.

**edit2**

I want to achive the following:

Go to the page /page.php with htaccess it should look like /page/homepage?background=someColor

In the homepage.php script I want to get 'homepage' as page variable and the get background should work.

Comment: I am unclear about your problem? Can you try to explain it with more examples?

Comment: Sorry even after reading your original and edited question 10+ times I am unable to understand what your problem is and what you want.

Comment: @anubhava tried to simplify it

Comment: ok see my answer below. I suspect you are looking for QSA flag in your rules.

Comment: Basically this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487909/htaccess-reverse-directory but then with 'working gets'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41735/discussion-between-john-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of current REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?param[]=$2 [L,QSA]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then 
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: See comment above please.

Comment: Ok now I remember writing that answer after lot of research. But what's not working from that answer?

Comment: I want the htaccess to ignore any ?get=var&in=the&request=itgets and append it after it's resolved. For some reason the question mark(?) gets removed somewhere in the htaccess. Thus ignored as get variable by php.

Comment: hmm QUERY_STRING shouldn't be dropping. Let me test it out.

Comment: Just ran a request `http://localhost/index/foo/bar/baz?color=red` and got `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = color=red`

Comment: 'QUERY_STRING' => string 'param=foo/bar/baz/color=red' (length=33), this is what I get. Should be 'QUERY_STRING' => string 'param=foo/bar/baz&color=red'

Comment: What was the original URL you entered in your browser?

Comment: localhost.dev/index/foo/bar/baz?color=red

Comment: Does this solution work for apache 2.2.22? I am not getting the 'param' parameter. And not 'redirect appends' but 'PATH_TRANSLATED' instead.