# htaccess different behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using the following htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of current REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?param[]=$2 [L,QSA]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

From the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155037/1127807 here.

But on my local machine it works perfectly but on my server it doesn't work at all and has different environment variables.

On my local server I have a few REDIRECT_REDIRECT_ variables in the $_SERVER variable, on my server I have 'PATH_TRANSLATED' and no REDIRECT_ in any form.

On my local server I would get a get called 'param' with the 'folder' names until a valid file is found but on my server I don't get anything like it.

Local versions:

```
Apache/2.4.2
PHP 5.4.4
```

Server versions:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
```

What do I have to change to achieve the same result?

**Localhost**

```
  'server' => 
    array (size=78)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
      'REDIRECT_MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
      'MIBDIRS' => string '/xampp/php/extras/mibs' (length=22)
      'MYSQL_HOME' => string '\xampp\mysql\bin' (length=16)
      'OPENSSL_CONF' => string '/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf' (length=29)
      'PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'PHPRC' => string '\xampp\php' (length=10)
      'TMP' => string '\xampp\tmp' (length=10)
      'HTTP_HOST' => string 'site.dev' (length=13)
      'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
      'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
      'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' (length=74)
      'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36' (length=108)
      'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip,deflate,sdch' (length=17)
      'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'en-US,en;q=0.8' (length=14)
      'HTTP_COOKIE' => string '__atuvc=122%7C45%2C160%7C46%2C409%7C47%2C53%7C48' (length=48)
      'PATH' => string ''... (length=559)
      'SystemRoot' => string 'C:\Windows' (length=10)
      'COMSPEC' => string 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (length=27)
      'PATHEXT' => string '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC' (length=53)
      'WINDIR' => string 'C:\Windows' (length=10)
      'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => string '<address>Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 Server at site.dev Port 80</address>
' (length=97)
      'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4' (length=45)
      'SERVER_NAME' => string 'site.dev' (length=13)
      'SERVER_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
      'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
      'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
      'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string 'Site/Public_domain' (length=56)
      'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
      'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => string '' (length=0)
      'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string 'Site/Public_domain' (length=56)
      'SERVER_ADMIN' => string 'postmaster@site.dev' (length=24)
      'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string 'Site/Public_domain/i.php' (length=62)
      'REMOTE_PORT' => string '60593' (length=5)
      'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' => string 'param[]=folder&param[]=file&param[]=foo&param[]=bar&bar=foo' (length=59)
      'REDIRECT_URL' => string '/i/' (length=3)
      'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
      'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.1' (length=8)
      'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
      'QUERY_STRING' => string 'param[]=folder&param[]=file&param[]=foo&param[]=bar&bar=foo' (length=59)
      'REQUEST_URI' => string '/i/folder/file/foo/bar?bar=foo' (length=30)
      'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/i.php' (length=6)
      'PHP_SELF' => string '/i.php' (length=6)
      'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1385767068.811
      'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1385767068
```

**Server**

```
  ["server"]=>
  array(28) {
    ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
    string(10) "*****"
    ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
    string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
    string(108) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
    string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch"
    ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
    string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
    string(14) "__atuvc=6%7C48"
    ["PATH"]=>
    string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
    ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
    string(6) "Apache"
    ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
    string(10) "****"
    ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
    string(11) "****"
    ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
    string(14) "****"
    ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
    string(56) "/var/www/site/Public_domain"
    ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
    string(16) "***"
    ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
    string(62) "/var/www/site/Public_domain/i.php"
    ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
    string(5) "50577"
    ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
    string(7) "CGI/1.1"
    ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
    string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
    string(7) "bar=foo"
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
    string(30) "/i/folder/file/foo/bar?bar=foo"
    ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
    string(6) "/i.php"
    ["PATH_INFO"]=>
    string(20) "/folder/file/foo/bar"
    ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
    string(39) "redirect:/folder/file/foo//file/foo/bar"
    ["PHP_SELF"]=>
    string(26) "/i.php/folder/file/foo/bar"
    ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
    int(1385767075)
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested this on `Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research this appears to be a registered bug in Apache. Read more about it here: [**`What is redirect:// in PATH_TRANSLATED?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113914/548225):

To **fix**, try this code with **`NS` flag**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L,NS]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is not a file then
# forward to the parent directory of current REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?param[]=$2 [L,QSA,NS]

# if current ${REQUEST_URI}.php is a valid file then
# load it be removing optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,NS]
```

Comment: Doesn't produce any get's either. The PATH_TRANSLATED however is now an absolute path. But with missing the actual script filename in it. For example: /var/www/site/i.php is the script and the request is /i/foo/bar I get /var/www/foo/bar.

Comment: I am not sure what 'NS' does except resolve 'path_translated' to a 'virtual(?)' path? The whole regex to get a get named 'param' if applicable is ignored/has no result.

Comment: Please check the link I provided for more details on this bug. I would suggest if possible get Apache upgraded to newer versions, if possible. I cannot reproduce this problem in 2 Apache versions I have.